# disk I/O error after usb standby

Tags: c#, sqlite, datareader, usb-drive

I get an exception with my SQLite Connection.

```
Message: disk I/O error
StackTrace: at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Reset(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 Source: System.Data.SQLite
```

This happens with this scenario.

1. I start the application
2. I click a button which executes the function
3. I do nothing for 30 minutes
4. I click the button again for executing the function
5. Exception!

The question is why?

The usb stick with the database goes in standby after a few minutes? Standby for hard disks is set up to 10 minutes on battery and 20 minutes on power supply.
Windows device manager says that the usb stick can be go in energy save mode if Windows wants.

But why the SQLite3.Reset function not work then?

And is there a solution to fix for?

Here is the function which I execute with 30 minutes interval.

```
if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Open();
}

using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
{
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    connection.Close();
}

return returnList;
```

Comment: Try calling `File.Exists(path to db file on usb stick)` before your query to see if the OS will wake up the usb stick.

Comment: A similar solution would be to check to see if the drive is in a ready state, and send a wake-up if not

Comment: @MadMyche how to send wake up to specific device?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield thank you for this idea. You mean before connection open I should check if file exist? But isn't there a better solution? Because the execute reader seems to be wrong :-(

Comment: If it works fine the first time you call it, why would there be something wrong with it the second time you call it? Unless you are changing parameter values, and not telling us?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Because I wait 10 minutes between both clicks and in this time the usb stick goes into standby mode. I do nothing except waiting.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion I gave you?

Comment: You can use the `DriveInfo` class to get the list of all drives, and then go through the properties use the `IsReady` property to see if it is ready.
If it is not ready, then you may be able to go through the properties to see why. I don't know the actual method to awaken.
Perhaps you could throw an _idle_ routine which would periodically read or write to the drive between executions, say every minute or so; to prevent it from going to sleep